# Outlook Calendar view will now show appointments

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

Outlook (Office Professional) 2016 - Windows 10.  I have 2 profiles in Outlook, a personal one, and one I use for Business.  Personal profile calendar works fine... I create appointments, they show up on the calendar. Business profile calendar is not behaving properly. (Email works properly though). Calendar view will not show any appointments (in day, work week, week or month view). If I change views to Preview, it does not work either... same behavior.  If I change views to 'List' or 'Active', I see my Appointments.  I have gone into 'Change View' and done a Reset, but that doesn't fix anything.  I have also done an Office 'Repair' operation.  It comes back really quick, and doesn't give an indication that it found any issues or repaired anything... (it just doesn't give a message). It has been working fine for 2 years... I am sure that something changed, but I am not sure what.  It was working one day, and when I used it the next day, no calendar entries were showing.  I am NOT one who goes in to mess with calendar views.   Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What’s your account type? Exchange, POP or IMAP?

As far as I know, this issue could be related with corrupted local data file. Please refer to this article to repair data file.

In addition, we can run /cleanviews command switch to see if it helps. To do this, please exit Outlook, press Win key + R to open the Run command, type outlook /cleanviews, press Enter. This will help reset all calendar view settings.

Comment: I tried /cleanviews.  It changed the layout of my Email, but did not help with Calendar issue.  Account type is MAPI.  You mentioned article to repair corrupted data file, but did not link or reference it.  Google will bring up many articles.  Did you have a specific article or tool in mind?  Thank you

Comment: Sorry,I forget to add the link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253